# Error while using Thinking Sphinx under Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

Im using Thinking-Sphinx as a plugin in my RoR app, but Im having this error:

**undefined method `define_index' for #**

What could it be?

Model

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :retailer_product
  has_many :group_ranges, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :group_clients, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :group_notifications, :dependent => :destroy

  define_index do
    indexes retailer_product.review
    indexes retailer_product.retailer.retailer_name
    indexes retailer_product.product.pr_id
    indexes retailer_product.product.product_name
    indexes retailer_product.product.product_tags.tag.tag, :as => :ptag #indexes tag.tag
    indexes retailer_product.product.product_properties.property.value, :as => :pvalue #indexes product_property.value
    indexes retailer_product.product.brand.brand, :as => :product_brand

    has :id

    where "groups.active=1"

    group_by "groups.id"
  end
end
```

Environment.rb

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file

# Specifies gem version of Rails to use when vendor/rails is not present
RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.8' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION

# Bootstrap the Rails environment, frameworks, and default configuration
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'boot')

ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT']="/project"

Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
  config.time_zone = 'UTC'
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
config.gem(
  'thinking-sphinx',
  :lib     => 'thinking_sphinx',
  :version => '1.3.11'
)
```

Please read:
http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/installing_thinking_sphinx.html

restart application after editing environment.rb

Comment: Thanks! Thats the right way to do it if you use it as a gem, and if you use it as a plugin you just have to put: require 'thinking_sphinx' at the beginning of the controller =)

Comment: You shouldn't have to require TS manually - in a controller or elsewhere - if installing as a plugin. It should just work. Did you do anything different to install it? Or just `script/plugin install git-url`?