# Rails thinking sphinx method

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

Im trying to set up thinking sphinx in my rails 3 app. I set up mysql and installed sphinx without error. In my gemfile i have

```
gem "riddle", "~> 1.5.0"
gem "thinking-sphinx", "~> 2.0.10"
```

These install fine. In my model i have

```
define_index do
    indexes :name
    indexes acad_field
    indexes expertise
    indexes interests
    indexes experience
    indexes marital_status
    indexes email
    indexes place_of_birth
    indexes birthyear
    indexes hometown
    indexes current_residence
    indexes languages
    indexes nationalities
    indexes ethnicities_mom_dad
    indexes institution
    indexes program

end
```

and in my index in my controller i have

```
def index
 #@profiles = Profile.all
 @profiles = Profile.search params[:search]
 respond_to do |format|
   format.html # index.html.erb
   format.json { render :json => @profiles }
 end
end
```

in my routes i have

```
match "profiles?search=:search", :to => "profiles#index"
```

when i try running a search i get the error

```
Routing Error

undefined method `define_index' for #<Class:0xb3ada670>
```

What i am doing wrong here.

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807509/error-while-using-thinking-sphinx-under-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just needed to run

```
rake thinking_sphinx:rebuild
```

in terminal

Answer (score 0):

Based on @fuzzyalej comment, the needed steps are:

- Replace correspondent gem line to `gem "thinking-sphinx", "~> 2.0.10", :require => 'thinking_sphinx'`
- You do not need add ?search=:search to routing match, because rails can accept GET variables without other specifications.

Answer (score 0):

you probably didn't run 'bundle install' after adding the gem specification in your gemfile, I don't think rake ts:rebuild actually solved this issue :)